# Updating Cells in 'user_flow_history' Sheet Based on 'users' Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

**Description:**

I am currently working on a Google Sheets project where I'm tracking user interactions using two sheets: 'users' and 'user_flow_history'. I'm facing a challenge in updating cells in the 'user_flow_history' sheet based on changes in the 'users' sheet.

**Scenario:**

In the 'users' sheet, I have two columns: A (for user IDs) and K (for flow names).
The 'user_flow_history' sheet has multiple columns, and all user IDs from 'users' sheet column A are transposed to the first row of this sheet.
When a user changes flows, I want to update the corresponding cell in the 'user_flow_history' sheet (in the same row as their user ID) with the new flow name from the 'users' sheet's column K.

**Spreadsheet Description:**

The spreadsheet contains various sheets of which two are the ones in question: 'users' and 'user_flow_history'.

```
'users' Sheet:
    Column A (A2:A): Contains user IDs.
    Column K (K2:K): Contains flow names. Each user ID corresponds to a flow name.

'user_flow_history' Sheet:
    The first row (A1:Α): Contains user IDs transposed from the 'users' sheet.
    Each column contains the various flow names (transposed from the 'users' sheet), which users, with corresponding user IDs in the first row, have passed through
```

**Objective:**

Every time a user changes their flow in the 'users' sheet, I want to automatically update the 'user_flow_history' sheet by finding the matching user ID and transposing the new flow name to the corresponding cell.

**Sample Data**

[image: Before edit:]

[image: Before edit]

[image: After edit: Users pass through different flows]

[image: After edit: Transposed view]

This is a Google Sheet that tracks multiple bot users as they navigate within various flows.

**Current Approach:**

I've tried using the onEdit trigger in Google Apps Script to accomplish this. However, despite ensuring the script is set up correctly, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. The script is designed to identify changes in the 'users' sheet column K and then look for the matching user ID in the 'user_flow_history' sheet. If a match is found, it should update the corresponding cell in the 'user_flow_history' sheet's corresponding row and column for the new flow name.

**Code:**

Here's the current version of the onEdit function in my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('users');
  if (sheet.getName() === 'users' && e.range.getColumn() === 11 /* Column K */) {
    var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
    var userId = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1 /* Column A */).getValue();
    var newValue = e.value;

    var historySheet = e.source.getSheetByName('user_flow_history');
    var historyValues = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, historySheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < historyValues.length; i++) {
      if (historyValues[i] === userId) {
        historySheet.getRange(1, i + 1).setValue(newValue);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Challenge:**

Despite setting up the script and trigger correctly (as far as I can see), the values are not being updated as intended in the 'user_flow_history' sheet. I've double-checked the sheet names, column indexes, and ranges, but I can't seem to identify the issue.

**Request:**

I'm seeking assistance in identifying what might be causing this script to not execute properly. Any insights into what I might be missing or any suggestions for an alternative approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't mean "ensuring the script is set up correctly"? The question looks to have too much context about the project but not enough details about the specific programming problem to be solved. Please describe the spreadsheet and add sample data corresponding to the state before and after the spreadsheet edit. Also, add information about how many users will be using the spreadsheet if there might be multiple users working simultaneously.

Comment: Added the information solicited.

Comment: Thanks. Data should be added as text instead of adding them as images.

Answer (score 0):

`historyValues` has the values of the first row, but it looks like you need the first column's values.

Replace

```
var historyValues = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, historySheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0];
```

by

```
var historyValues = historySheet.getRange('A:A').getValues().flat();
```

or

```
var historyValues = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, historySheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
```

Use `getLastRow()` instead of `getMaxRows()` because the first will return the last row of the sheet data range (the last row holding a value) while the second will return the sheet number of rows which is very common that is larger than the first one. When using this value on getRange to set range size and after that, the range values, the returned values will have a lot of `''` (empty strings). This might be a problem because it will consume more computing resources and lead to errors.

Also you need to change

```
 historySheet.getRange(1, i + 1).setValue(newValue);
```

to

```
 historySheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(newValue);
```

because the first parameter correspond to the row and the second to the column.

References

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).
- [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score 0):

This `var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('users');`

should be `const sheet = e.range.getSheet()` otherwise it will work on all sheets and I'm guessing that's not what you want

Writing it this way makes better use of event object and helps it to run a little faster

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'users' && e.range.columnStart === 11 /* Column K */) {
    var e.range.rowStart = e.range.getRow();
    var userId = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
    var hsh = e.source.getSheetByName('user_flow_history');
    var hvs = hsh.getRange(1, 1, 1, hsh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < hvs.length; i++) {
      if (hvs[i] === userId) {
        hsh.getRange(1, i + 1).setValue(e.value);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both, the code you have supplied and that of @Rubén. In both cases, I have made a minor change so that the starting row is row 2 because both files have headers. Unfortunately, I have not been able to achieve the desired result with neither of the two codes. I am supplying the link to a copy of the sheet, hoping that it will be of help: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vM_tFMKHMxPsf8JKE-1ejhcHAu9wkeVc7qB0M_0dk6s/edit?usp=sharing[link]